# Dynamic vs static memory allocation of buffers for network I/O and C++

Tags: c++, memory-management

I'm not sure if topic is right, but I'll try to explain my problem below. What I'm looking for is some kind of "academic answer", because I suppose that my both solutions give similar results at runtime.

I have a C++ program on Linux, which perform lot of network I/O operations and I wonder if it's better to built-in buffer into client's class or allocate it dynamically. First solution using built-in buffers:

```
template <size_t buffer_size> class Buffer
{
    // ...

    char buffer [buffer_size];
}

class TcpClient
{
    // ...

    Buffer<1024> input_buffer;
    Buffer<1024> output_buffer;
}
```

Second using dynamically allocated buffers:

```
class Buffer 
{
    Buffer (size_t buffer_size) :
        buffer (malloc (buffer_size))
    {
        // ...
    }

    // ...

    char* buffer; 
}

class TcpClient 
{
    // ...

    Buffer input_buffer (1024);
    Buffer output_buffer (1024); 
}
```

Now, comparing both solutions I see that first requires less memory allocation operations then second one, next thing - thanks to templates compiler knows class size at compile time. First solution should give better reference locality (?) and compiler can also align class size to whatever it want. Also we have direct access to buffers, because we do not need to perform additional pointer dereference operation.

I started thinking how TcpClient objects from first solution behave in processors cache. Each time we access such object in code it's loaded into processors cache and it's buffers are copied too, even if we do not need them. It can make cache inefficient, because we store there a lot data what increase memory lookup faults probability, right?

Isn't it a waste of processor's time to copy buffers to cache all the time? 
What are other effects of both solutions from processor and operating system point of view?
Is it better to keep class size small or build int it as much as we can?

Comment: You can allocate your buffers on the stack, using members to your class. By the way you code C++, use new, not malloc !

Comment: "Each time we access such object in code it's loaded into processors cache and it's buffers are copied too" - that's not quite true. On any architecture I can think of, memory is cached by fixed-size pages/lines (depending what cache), regardless of where the objects are. Use a line, that line is loaded. If you were to create an array of `TcpClient` objects, and do a lot of operations on them which don't use the buffer, then an external buffer *could* mean you fit more than one object in a line and speed things up a bit. Otherwise, no difference on that account.

Answer (score 4):

The processor won't look up memory differently depending on where it is. Allocating on the stack is much faster, much less error-prone. Only use dynamic allocation if the allocation needs to be *dynamic*, that is, you need a variable lifetime or type of an object. Else, use static allocation.

Answer (score 3):

I would not be so concerned with cache effects here. Socket I/O is slow and cache inefficient anyway because it requires system calls and data copying from the kernel buffer to the user space, there is no POSIX way to do zero-copy socket I/O (you can do that with custom hardware though). The best you can do is minimize the number of syscalls required to send and receive data through the socket.

The size of your user space receive buffer ideally should be the same as the size of the socket receive buffer in the kernel. This way you can read all the received data in one `recv/recvmsg/read()` syscall.

If you don't create clients many times a second it may not matter much how many allocations are required to construct the object. It is often better to identify and optimize the fast path of your I/O, so that once the client object has been constructed sending and receiving data does not involve memory allocations and data copies in the user space.